# Android - Encrypt and decrypt data using fingerprint authentication

Tags: android

I'm facing problem from 3 days. I need to save a text from EditText into SharedPreferences. This text should be saved encrypted in SharedPreference after user authenticated with fingerprint scanner. Then I need to decrypt, later, this data so I need a permanent storage mechanism for the SecretKey generated.

```
private SecretKey createKey(String keyName) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setKeySize(DEFAULT_KEY_SIZE)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
            .build());
    return keyGenerator.generateKey();
}
```

Problem is happen when I try to load `KeyStore` from file using `FileInputStream`:

```
public static SecretKey getKeyFromKeystore(Context context) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(KEYSTORE_FILENAME);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    // FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(KEYSTORE_FILENAME);
    keyStore.load(fis, null);
    SecretKey keyStoreKey = null;

    try {
        keyStoreKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(CONFIDENTIALITY_KEY, null);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return  keyStoreKey;

}
```

I'm getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream not supported
>   at
>   android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:930)

Without `.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)` I don't have this problem but I don't think this is the right way to use fingerprint's security.

Answer (score 5):

Android Keystore's storage is located outside of your app's process. Thus, you don't need to store it into or load it from a file. All you need to do is invoke `keyStore.load(null)` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RxFingerprint](https://github.com/Mauin/RxFingerprint) may be it solve your problem.   Also [Read This](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm already use RxFingerprint and I didn't find any way to store keystore or secretkey for later decryption in this library.